# Setting colorbox lightbox ajax href variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I am currently getting bad request in the colorbox when it pops up:

Is there away that I could feed the href using a $ variable?

```
ajaxCall: function ajaxCall(url, data_array, div_id, callback_fn)    {


var d = ajaxCall(url, data_array, "rhs_info", "do_quicklist_actions");

            d.done(function(data) {
                        $.colorbox({href:"$data"})
            });
```

Comment: what does data result in? are you wanting to use that as your variable?

Comment: @KaiQing var d is the Deferred Object that is now classified as "$data" this is what I am wanting to use as my variable

Comment: I sort of meant what does it literally resolve to. So are you expecting it to reference an element, so the result would be href:"`http://www....`" or href:$('#some-element'). And since you declare data, would it not just be href:data

Comment: @KaiQing I have updated my question with what ajaxCall is I am wanting it to load the href that is rhs_info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing quotes from `$data`, like:

```
$.colorbox({href:$data});
```